# git push : pack-objects died of signal 11

Tags: git, github

i'm getting the following fatal error when trying to upload about 1GB of source files (none larger than 10MB) to github :

```
root@crow:/home/username/data1/htdocs/localhost# git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 10587, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10587/10587), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
error: pack-objects died of signal 11
error: pack-objects died of signal 11
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/nicerapp/nicerapp.git'
```

Comment: `signal 11` indicates a bug of some sort. What Git version are you running, on what system?

Comment: ubuntu 20.04, default repository for git..

Comment: bitbucket.org (hosted in Australia), does work, btw.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder which end is having `git pack-objects` die (yours, or the GitHub one)...